# Horizontally distribute along path

Tags: adobe-illustrator, alignment, brush, blending-objects

How can I horizontally distribute objects along a path? `Blend` and `Brushes` don't work for me because they distribute objects evenly according to the distance along the path.

I began by using the `Blend` method from this [question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5044/distribute-objects-along-a-path-in-illustrator). However, as shown below, the points aren't horizontally distributed as I would like. How do I get to the path and and objects displayed at the bottom of the figure below?

[image]

Comment: I am pretty sure you could do it by creating a brush, what did you try by using brushes?

Comment: When I tried using a brush, I followed this: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/how-to-make-objects-follow-a-path-illustrator-like-on-the-las-vegas-sign. However, I ran into the same problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can use a scripting environment that can detect bezier intersections, this is very easy to achieve. Unfortunately, Adobe does not include these methods in their scripting toolkit. Instead, I mainly use Scriptographer or Paper.js, but I believe Inkscape can find bezier intersections as well. Here's Mike Kamermans's excellent primer on the math for those interested: [Bezier curve intersections](http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#intersections).

The following is a script for paper.js / scriptographer that aligns a set of ungrouped, selected objects to the first intersection of the top-most selected path:

```
var sel = document.selectedItems;
var sel0 = sel[0];
sel.splice( 0, 1 );
var pathOffset = new Point( 0, 500 );
var line = new Path.Line( sel[0].position + pathOffset, sel[0].position - pathOffset );
for ( i = 0; i < sel.length; i++ ) {
    line.position = sel[i].position;
    lineIntersections = line.getIntersections(sel0);
    if (lineIntersections !== null && lineIntersections.length > 0) {
        sel[i].position = lineIntersections[0].point;
    }
}
line.remove();
```

Here's a .gif of the process and result:

[image: Align objects to intersection with a path]

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even know paper.js existed. It's also solves some other problems I've had.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily distribute all the points so the space between them is even. Simply select the points and click the **Distribute Horizontal Space** button on the **Align Panel**. You'll then have to ***manually move the points vertically to meet your line.***

[image: align]

If you do not see the Distribute Spacing options on the Align panel, Choose `Show Options` from the Align Panel menu.

There is no method, I'm aware of, which will evenly distribute objects horizontally while at the same time following a vertical contour *without* distorting the objects themselves.

Brushes will distort objects in 99.5% of cases. Blends, while capable of even distribution *along* their spine, are not capable of distribution which *ignores* the blend spine (which is what you are after).

I don't know if this fits your needs, but what about simply using a **Dashed Stroke**?

[image: stroke]

You could alter the gap distances where needed.

Comment: Thanks, you've answered my question. Unfortunately for me, as you've pointed out, the answer is "No, it's not possible".

Comment: Objects are distributed horizontally, but it's the vertical space which is changed. I should remove the "vertically" it's merely confusing there.

Comment: The dashed stroke idea is clever. It's like a brush but without the distortion. However, horizontal distribution of the points along the bottom of the page are a must have for me. The dashed line doesn't accomplish that without manually editing alot of gaps. I have 100+ objects for several files; manual editing just isn't an option.