# Where is "Distribute Horizontal Space" in Inkscape 1.0+?

Tags: inkscape, alignment, distribute

Apologies all - I was looking for a way to (easily) enter a distance between objects textually (like Align, but with specified distance like 1 cm); I had apparently found a post about something like that, but for Illustrator, did not notice that difference, and started looking for  "Distribute Horizontal Space" in Inkscape, even if it was never there -- and stumbled upon the below link... So, this question resulted from that error, and I'll try to reformulate it:

Using Inkscape 1.0.2-2 (e86c870879, 2021-01-15) on Windows 10, and I'm looking for a way to specify horizontal or vertical distance between edges of bounding boxes of objects textually; basically, like Align, but with also with numeric offset distance.

I found something similar here - apparently in Adobe Illustrator, there is something called "Distribute Horizontal Space" [Horizontally distribute along path](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/25945/horizontally-distribute-along-path) :

> ... click the Distribute Horizontal Space button on the Align Panel ...
>
> [image: align]

I made the mistake of interpreting the above screenshot as one from Inkscape, but if one compares the Align panel from Inkscape, there is no such function:

[image: align_inkscape_1.0.2]

Is there something like Adobe Illustrator's "Distribute Horizontal Space" in Inkscape 1.0.2 - and if so, how do I get to it?

Comment: The first dialog you are showing is not from Inkscape. It's from Adobe Illustrator. What are you actually trying to achieve? Can you please [edit your question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/147662/edit) and post an image showing what you are trying to do?  Then it might be possible to tell you how to achieve it in Inkscape.  Forget about Illustrator. Although they are similar in that both are vector image eidtors, the interfaces are completely different, and there are different ways to achieve the same thing.

Comment: Thanks @BillyKerr - turns out, I misread that post as for Inkscape, did not realize it was for Illustrator until you posted ... So I reformulated the question now to mention it, I hope it makes sense now.

Comment: I've added an answer now for exact numeric spacing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want exact numeric spacing you can use the *Remove Overlaps* feature in Inkscape's Align and Distribute panel. Note that the objects don't actually have to overlap, despite the name.

Here's an example

[image]

Comment: Many thanks - this is what I needed, so moved the accept here

Answer (score 3):

In the Distribute portion of your second image, the right-most icon represents a text-related action. The icon immediately to the left shows spaces between the representative objects, with an indication of equalizing the space. This is the horizontal space distribution action.

Starting from the left on the first line of Distribute, you see: align left edges, align center of objects, align right edges, followed by space between objects.