# Can I generate series of one object around a curve line in illustrator cc?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, tools, blending

I drew a golden cup which you can see below by illustrator.
Actually I am looking for speeding up ways for drawing .
I'm familiar with blend tool which we can create series of shapes if we have first shape and last shape , but its happen along straight line.
I want to know if we can blend objects along curve and path .

[image]

as you see in image , there are some leaves that are located around the curve line.

I wanted to know can I generate these leaves around a curve line by using some tools (or maybe blend tool ) in illustrator instead of drawing each leaf ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright well this is somewhat two different questions. For help with your leaf issue you might want to see this related question: [Distribute objects along a path in Illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5044/distribute-objects-along-a-path-in-illustrator)

Now as far as blending along a path, sure.

Can use `Replace Spine`:

[image: Replace Spine]

or manually adjust the path however you want, this works before or after replacing the spine. Its just like any other path:

1. First create your blend:

[image: Original Blend]

2. Now add anchor point(s) to the newly created path:

[image: Blend with anchor point added]

3. Adjust like any other path:

[image: Blend along path]

Answer (score 3):

**Replace the spine of a blend**.

Create a blend. 
Draw a path that you want the blend to follow
Select the blend and your path
Choose `Object > Blend > Replace Spine`

This will replace the straight path of the blend with your new path, whatever it is.

[image]

More info on blends can be found by reviewing the [help files](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/blending-objects.html).